# Can't remove the right margin

Tags: html, css, margin

Here's the part of the HTML:

```
<fieldset>
  <table class="pensioners-view-tbl-pension-info"
  </table>
<fieldset>
```

Here's the CSS related to those two elements:

```
  fieldset { border-radius:7px;padding-top:15px;}
  .pensioners-view-tbl-pension-info { margin-left: 5%;}
```

And here' the sanpshot of the UI:[image]

As you can see I have not set any constraints regarding the right margins, neither in fieldset as padding-right, nor in the table itself as margin-right. How can I remove the right margin of the table, at least shift it to the right a bit?
 I've tried to set the table width to 100% but it doesn't work, it just crosses away the fieldset.

EDIT: Here's the [JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K4LPa/)

Comment: There's hacks for sure, but without a more **live** example it's difficult to determine the cause, and our goal is to solve this in a clean way. Perhaps a fiddle?

Comment: Learn the box model and hover each ancestor in the tree starting from <html> and see which one is restricting the freedom of this element.

Comment: I've edited my question and added the JSFiddle link

Comment: Perhaps a parent element of the fieldset has less than 100% width set?

Comment: @TomWijsman, as seen in the snapshot and in the jsfiddle, there's nothing else between fieldset and the table, table is the direct child. So checking each node in the tree seems pointless to me. How come the fieldset occupies the entire area but does not let the table to do so?

Comment: @11684, then in that case the fieldset itself should have been narrower, right?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't see it in the snapshot. @MikeJM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the margin on the table, give it a 100% width. Then add padding to the fieldset.

You forgot to remove the margin, which offsets the entire width against the fieldset.

Comment: You were right. It did the job. But how can I have the table margined form the left still filling the rest off the area?

Comment: I did this by just extending the width of the middle column. But I still think there must be a more proper way.

Comment: The padding on the fieldset should be able to let you do that, I think.